# Searchkick aggregations by a model's class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, searchkick

My searchkick implementation searches across multiple indexes. It looks like this:

```
@results = Searchkick.search(
  params[:query],
  index_name: [Actors, Producers, Directors],
  fields: ["name"],
  indices_boost: {Actors => 4, Producers => 8, Directors => 2},
  page: params[:page],
  per_page: cookies[:per_page]
  )
```

How can I implement aggregations so I can filter the results based on class (actors, producers, directors)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the following search_data to my model.

```
def search_data
 {
   name: name,
   class_name: self.class.name
 }
end
```

And then updated the controller with:

```
@results = Searchkick.search(
  params[:query],
  index_name: [Actors, Producers, Directors],
  fields: ["name"],
  indices_boost: {Actors => 4, Producers => 8, Directors => 2},
  aggs: {class_name:{}},
  page: params[:page],
  per_page: cookies[:per_page]
  )
```